# Deploy meteor app without client on server

Tags: meteor

I'm working on a meteor app for iOS and Android and only need the server for my mongoDB backend. Per default I also have a client website on the production server which I dont need because my clients should be mobile only (via native app )

How to remove the client on the server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't create a simple main.js and inside place an

```
if(Meteor.isServer){
 //server code (mongoDB)
}
```

and

```
if(Meteor.isCordova){
  //Devices Code
}
```

or maybe i don't get you question, sorry

Comment: This will work but I would like to do it from 'the other side' because I never need the client website on my server. Is the cordova code only working when I put it on a 'cordova' folder like the Client/Server folders? I dont like the if statements that much.

Comment: well this suxx, but no.. for now there is not a `cordova` folder, take a look at [this](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/3409) GitHub issue, its still open and active (last comment 4 days ago).